# How can i make information pop up in index.html if i typed and sent it in send.html using js

Tags: javascript, html

I have an page where i need to put new information everyday
and to not always make a new html file, i need js to send and receive the message, like a blog post

I already tried

```
<script>
fetch("sus.txt", {credentials: "cement"}).then(resp => resp.text()).then(text => {

  content.innerText = text
})
</script>
```

but it failed because CORS policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bypass this policy, you can set up a simple server-side script that serves the content you want to display

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```